# Simple game using python

Tags: python

college student here and I am working of one of my first real coding assignments using python. The main problem is that when it gets to question 1 and the user answers yes or no i get an error. I think that because used "if q1 == "yes"" if the user types yes it should print the next line or if the user types no then it should continue to the next question. Any help much appreciated remember first coding class for me.

```
def main():
    print("this is the common sense game.")
    n = eval(input("to begin please type 1: "))


    print("question 1: Do they have a fourth of July in England? ")
    q1 = eval(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q1 == "yes": 
        print(" no there is a fourth of July in America GAME OVER.")

    print("question 2: are there three outs in an inning of baseball?")
    q2 = eval(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q2 == "yes":
        print("no there are six GAME OVER")

    print("question 3: is it right to ignore a problem until it goes away? ")
    q3 = eval(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q3 == "no":
        print("solve the problem the moment it occurs don't wait GAME OVER")
    else:
        print("Common sense is instinct, but enough of it is Genius" "YOU WIN")
    main()
main()
```

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: Please, for future problems, reduce the amount of code. In this case, just four lines should have been enough. Also, throw the actual error text at a searchengine for research and then include it verbatim in your question here.

Comment: using eval because that was the way it was taught to me first day. i need the code to evaluate user input.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) if you're using Python 2, or [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) for Python 3 instead of `eval(input(`.

This line:

```
print("Common sense is instinct, but enough of it is Genius" "YOU WIN")
```

has an error as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result of the user-input to a string. In your code, the if-statement is testing `if q1 == "yes"`, not `if q1 == some variable named 'yes'`. So, you need to change `eval()` to `str()` in your questions:

```
def main():
    print("this is the common sense game.")
    n = input("to begin please type 1: ")


    print("question 1: Do they have a fourth of July in England? ")
    q1 = str(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q1 == "yes": 
        print(" no there is a fourth of July in America GAME OVER.")

    print("question 2: are there three outs in an inning of baseball?")
    q2 = str(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q2 == "yes":
        print("no there are six GAME OVER")

    print("question 3: is it right to ignore a problem until it goes away? ")
    q3 = str(input("enter yes or no: "))
    if q3 == "no":
        print("solve the problem the moment it occurs don't wait GAME OVER")
    else:
        print("Common sense is instinct, but enough of it is Genius" "YOU WIN")
    main()
main()
```

Comment: This worked i had to create two variables yes = "yes" and no = "no" then python recognized that instead of just a random string.

Comment: Is there any reason you need `eval()` in your code? You are using Python 3, so just using `input()` should be enough.

Comment: using eval because that was the way it was taught. we are in like week 7 of the first coding class many of us have ever taken so you will have to excuse my ignorance when it might look like old code.